# Regex - negate a group within a class

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java's matcher to group terms in a string using the following regex:

`Pattern.compile("(\\\\\"[^\\\\\"]*\\\\\"|[^\\s\\\\\"]+)");`

This is the part I'm having trouble with: [^\s\\\"]

I'd like it to only match non-spaces and dangling escaped quotes such as \". Is there any way to group the \\ and \" within a character class so they're only matched together?

I tried to use lookahead/lookbehind, but found that including it within the character class put me back at square one.

Comment: Are you asking for a pattern to match a sequence of characters that contains neither spaces nor escaped quotes (i.e. \") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character class matches a *single* character. If I understood you correctly, you want to match only the string `\"`. To do this, you don't need a character class at all--the regex `\\"` matches that already! (Inside a Java string, it would look like `\\\\\"` which is ridiculous, but there you have it.)

You can group things together using parentheses: `(\\\\\")`. You can also alternate inside a group like this using `|`. So to match non-spaces *or* `\"`, you can do this: `(\S|\\\\\")`. (Note that `\S` is the same as `[^\s]`.)

<strike>EDIT: I wasn't paying enough attention. You can match everything but `\"` or a space as follows: `(\\\\(?!")|[^\s\\])`, I think.</strike>

How about this: `([^\\s\\\\]|\\\\(?!"))`. This should match anything except whitespace or `\` *or* a `\` not followed by a `"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm trying to negate the \\\\\" part as well and I tried things like (\S|^\\\\\")+ or (\S|(?!\\\\\"))+ but had no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I got a little bit confused. Do you want to match everything *except* spaces and `\"`?

Comment: Here's what I ended up using:

`"(\\\\\"[^\\\\\"]*\\\\\"|((\\\\(?!\")|[^\\s\\\\\"])+))"`,

I needed to preserve the escape character so that it wouldn't get stripped from other special characters in the string (eg \n becoming n). But this does exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!